# "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol" Error Trying to Reach Outlook smtp Server

Tags: outlook, smtp, openssl, live-sdk, sslv3

I'm trying to send emails from an Outlook account in my iOS application. I'm using Mailcore2 and Outlook's Live-SDK. I am able to receive emails, but get an error when I try to send emails: "a stable connection to the server could not be established".

To investigate the issue, I went into the terminal and tried to connect via SSL:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect smtp-mail.outlook.com:587
```

The response I got back was:

```
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown  protocol:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:607
```

I don't know exactly what this error means, after a bit of searching I found that a common response to this issue was that the server I am trying to reach may not support a necessary SSL protocol. This site: http://foundeo.com/products/iis-weak-ssl-ciphers/test.cfm allows you to test which SSL protocols are enabled for a particular domain. Using this I found that SSLV2 is disabled and SSLV3 is also disabled.

I not clear on what all this means or what I might need to do to connect to this server. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SMTP connections to port 587 starts unencrypted. Encryption may be turned out later using `STARTTLS` command in SMTP session if server supports it.

`openssl` supports `STARTTLS` for some protocols including SMTP. It requires `-starttls smtp` command line options as described in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645854/2139766

---

Outlook.com does not seem to support smtps: 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app

Comment: Thanks, but no luck with 465.

Comment: I was able to get in from the command line using startTLS: openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp-mail.outlook.com:587 Thanks!