# Apache james 3.0 Verify and test startTLS

Tags: java, apache, james, starttls

I have recently configured the Apache james 3.0 beta5 to support startTLS. I have generated the keystore file and set it in the smtpserver.xml and run the james server with no problem or error.

I need to verify and confirm it actually works and I am not sure how to do so.

Can anyone please help me out by showing me the best way to verify this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> openssl s_client -connect localhost:nnn -starttls smtp

Then you can type the regular SMTP commands (ex, ehlo example.com).

The port number nnn has to be the same that has been configured in the smtpserver.xml.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640560/openssl-to-negotiate-ssl-encryption-for-starttls

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You can configure your mail client to use startTLS for POP3 and SMTP. This is easy.
For remote delivery we used https://www.checktls.com/live/testreceiver.html and https://www.checktls.com/live/testsender.html